# request.user.is_authenticated не работает в html шаблоне django

Tags: python, django

страница выводится, views отрабатывает, но почему не видит, что пользователь залогинен? почему не выводит "ЭТО НЕТ" в шаблоне?

**base.html**

```
<!doctype html>
  <body>
    ЭТО ВИДНО
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    ЭТО НЕТ
    {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

- в админке залогинился
- install_apps заводские настройки, стоят     'django.contrib.admin','django.contrib.auth','django.contrib.contenttypes'

может что-то в context views надо добавить?

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from .models import News, Category

class HomeNews(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'news/home_news_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'news'
    
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Главная страница'

        return context
```

Comment: уберите request 
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
 ...

Comment: Да и проще всего получить объектыиз таблицы:  model = News.objects.all()

Comment: не помогло {% if user.is_authenticated %}

Comment: решение - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253040/не-работает-в-html-if-request-user-is-authenticated-python-django