# не работает в html {% if request.user.is_authenticated %} python django

Tags: python, django

Имеется такой HTML код:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
     Добро пожаловать, {{ user.username }} | <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Выход</a>
 {% else %}
     <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a> | <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
 {% endif %}
```

- Не выводит что залогинен пользователь, хотя в админку заходит и показывает, что пользователь авторизован.
- Так:
  `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}`
  тоже пробовал.

Может потому что это выводиться через `tags.py` и туда надо передать `request`?

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам, просто если мы используем inclusion_tag, тогда надо передавать контест еще раз

```
@register.inclusion_tag('../templates/include/_nav.html', takes_context=True)
def navigation(context):  
    #some code 
    return context
```